# Terço e Terceiro

Tags: etimologia, origem

Me surgiu uma dúvida com relação à definição dos nomes dos números ordinais e frações em Português. Todos os números usados em frações se escrevem da mesma forma que os ordinais, com exceção do terceiro:

| Fração | Ordinal |
| --- | --- |
| Um meio (1/2) | Segundo (2ª) |
| Um terço (1/3) | Terceiro (3ª) |
| Um quarto (1/4) | Quarto (4ª) |
| Um quinto (1/5) | Quinto (5ª) |
| Um sexto (1/6) | Sexto (6ª) |
| Um sétimo (1/7) | Sétimo (7ª) |
| Um oitavo (1/8) | Oitavo (8ª) |
| Um nono (1/9) | Nono (9ª) |
| Um décimo (1/10) | Décimo (10°) |

Apenas "terço" é diferente da sua versão ordinal. Reparei que em outras línguas vindas do Latim (das que pesquisei) também existem palavras diferentes para "Terceiro" e "Terço".

Alguém teria alguma ideia do porquê? Obrigado!

Comment: Primeiramente, bela tabela! Segundamente, o segundo também é diferente: «metade/meio» ≠ «segundo». Uma coisa interessante é que «terço» pode significar tanto uma fração (1/3) ou ordem (3º), mas este uso é considerado “pouco usado”, senão arcaico.

Comment: @Schilive hahaha obrigado! Eu cheguei a pensar que o segundo também seria, mas ao contrário dos outros, ele não possui uma versão "Um  ___", sendo só utilizado o "meio" mesmo.

Comment: Reparei que utilizei "cardinal" no lugar de "ordinal", realizei a edição corrigindo isto.

Comment: @Lucius, interessante sua observação. Não tenho resposta a ela. Sobre 1/2, "um meio" existe sim.

Comment: @Lucius Me dei a liberdade de editar tua pergunta para incluir o 1/2 na tabela, já que ele se encaixa perfeitamente na pergunta. Claro que você pode desfazer se preferir. Sobre não se usar "um meio", usa-se para se referir a frações, veja, por exemplo: [1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Um_meio), [2](http://mdmat.mat.ufrgs.br/anos_iniciais/fracoes/fracoes_09.htm), [3](http://www.matematicadidatica.com.br/FracaoLeitura.aspx), [4](https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/matematica/nomenclatura-fracao.htm), [5](http://www.uel.br/projetos/matessencial/basico/fundamental/fracoes.html), etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127382/discussion-between-schilive-and-stafusa).

Comment: E o significado de Terceto     ?

Answer (score 2):

Antes de cerca do século I a.C. (antes de Cristo), os romanos não tinham palavras específicas para as frações, eles não tinham nenhum nome para 1/7, mas tinham *semis* (1/2), *triens* (1/3), quadrans (1/4), *septunx* (7/12), dentre outros. No período clássico, os romanos começam a usar os ordinais, de *tertius* em diante, para frações, então, *tertius* designava tanto 1/3 quanto 3º — inclusive diziam *tertia pars*, *terça parte*.

A palavra "terceiro" [se origina](https://dicionario.priberam.org/terceiro) de *tertiarĭus*, que significa "que contém um terço" e, [no latim medieval](https://www.wordsense.eu/tertiarius/), também "[Ordem terceira](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordem_terceira)" (ordem religiosa de leigos católicos). Já se usavam "terço" (ou "teerço") e terceiro (ou "tercer") no século XIII. No francês e no italiano também há distinção, e inclusive têm as mesmas origens, *tertĭus* para os fracionários (1/3) e *tertiarĭus* para os ordinais (3º).

Em português, em algum momento entre 562, quando começou a usar-se *terça-feira*, e 1200, quando *tercer*/*terceiro* já se usava, o uso de *terço* quase se restringiu ao fracionário, sendo *terço* como ordinal pouco usado.

Fontes: [Literary Evidence for Roman Arithmetic with F vidence for Roman Arithmetic with Fractions](https://ecommons.luc.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1024&context=classicalstudies_facpubs) e [A polissemia dos ordinais, do latim ao português: a permanência de um fenômeno lingüístico](https://revistadaanpoll.emnuvens.com.br/revista/article/view/266).

Mais especulativamente:

> Uma suposição poderia portanto ser que essa distinção tenha começado no latim e que as duas palavras se mantido no vocabulário por conta das ordens religiosas e, possivelmente devido ao claro caráter hierárquico da palavra, dominou (comparado a ‘terço’) o sentido ordinal.
>
> Claro que isso é especulativo e, na mesma linha, ‘segundo’ tem um sentido quase pejorativo de menor importância, o tornando natural para o uso como ordinal, enquanto o conceito de dividir na parte central, no ‘meio’, é bastante evocativo para se referir à metade, 1/2. — [*Stafusa, usuário do site.*]

> Havendo duas opções para 3º, *terço* e *terceiro*, a palavra *terceiro* começou a ser mais usada, porquanto *terço* poderia causar ambigüidades” — [*Schilive, usuário do site.*]